# AWS Codebuild failing on vite build step, no such file

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, vite, aws-codepipeline

I'm trying to deploy an application using Codebuild and Codepipeline. The build step is failing with the following error:

> [Container] 2023/12/07 21:04:14.861488 Running command echo Installing
> source NPM dependencies...
> Installing source NPM dependencies...
>
> [Container] 2023/12/07 21:04:14.869323 Running command npm install
>
> added 3 packages, and audited 275 packages in 2s
>
> 97 packages are looking for funding   run `npm fund` for details
>
> found 0 vulnerabilities
>
> [Container] 2023/12/07 21:04:31.721180 Phase complete: PRE_BUILD State: SUCCEEDED
> [Container] 2023/12/07 21:04:31.721199 Phase context status code:  Message:
> [Container] 2023/12/07 21:04:31.751993 Entering phase BUILD
>
> [Container] 2023/12/07 21:04:31.759628 Running command npm run build
>
> > my-app-name@0.0.0 build
> >
> > vite build
>
> /codebuild/output/src1216840642/src/node_modules/.bin/vite: line 1:
> ../vite/bin/vite.js: No such file or directory
>
> [Container] 2023/12/07 21:04:32.242055 Command did not exit successfully npm run build exit status 127
> [Container] 2023/12/07 21:04:32.247589 Phase complete: BUILD State: FAILED
> [Container] 2023/12/07 21:04:32.247609 Phase context status code: COMMAND_EXECUTION_ERROR Message: Error while executing command: npm run build. Reason: exit status 127

It runs fine locally. I'm using node18 and the image is aws/codebuild/amazonlinux2-x86_64-standard:5.0. My buildspec is the following:

```
version: 0.2

phases:
  install:
    runtime-versions:
      nodejs: 18
  pre_build:
    commands:
      - echo Installing source NPM dependencies...
      - npm install
  build:
    commands:
      - echo Build started...
      - codebuild-breakpoint
      - npm run build
  post_build:
    commands:
      - aws s3 cp --recursive --acl public-read ./build s3://<<MY_BUCKET_NAME>>/
      - aws s3 cp --acl public-read --cache-control="max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate" ./build/index.html s3://<<MY_BUCKET_NAME>>/
      - aws cloudfront create-invalidation --distribution-id <<MY_DISTRO_ID>> --paths /index.html
artifacts:
  files:
    - "build/*"
    - "build/**/*"
```

Anyone know what might be causing it to not find vite, even though `npm install` ran successfully, or how I might go about debugging the failure?

Comment: Can you please replace `npm install` with `npm ci` and retry? And also replace `npm run build` with `npm run build --verbose` and update your question with the updated output please. Please also add your `package.json` to the question.

Comment: I guess something had gone wrong with the packages because `npm ci` fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

Using `npm ci` instead of `npm install` worked as suggested in the comments.

Comment: This is OK but best practice is to tag the person making the comment that worked as an answer & allowing them some time to post an answer if possible :)